# How can I connect to an external JVM using Inline::Java?

Tags: java, perl, jvm, perl-module

How can I connect to an external, already-running JVM using [`Inline::Java`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Java)?

I'm trying to connect to a running OSGi app so I can send and receive objects, arrays, lists, etc. As I understand it, [`Inline::Java`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Java) creates its own JVM to run the Java code on; all I need to figure out is how to communicate between that JVM and the one running the app.

I tried using RMI, with the following code for the client:

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import example.hello.Hello;

public class Client {

    private Client() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            String response = stub.sayHello();
            System.out.println("response: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I compile and run this separately, it works, but when I try to embed the code into a Perl script using `Inline::Java`, it gives an error:

```
C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test>perl hello.pl

A problem was encountered while attempting to compile and install your Inline
Java code. The command that failed was:
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation  -d "C:\Users\j
osesong\Documents\RMI_Test\lib\auto\hello_pl_5a5a" Client.java > cmd.out 2>&1
```

The build directory was:

```
C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test\build\hello_pl_5a5a
```

The error message was:

```
Client.java:3: error: package example.hello does not exist
import example.hello.Hello;
                    ^
Client.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            ^
  symbol:   class Hello
  location: class Client
Client.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
                          ^
  symbol:   class Hello
  location: class Client
3 errors
```

To debug the problem, I `cd`'d to the build directory and inspected the output file, which looked like this:

```
 at hello.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hello.pl line 2.
```

What could be causing this?

The perl script:

```
use Inline (Java => Config => DIRECTORY => 'C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test');
use Inline Java => 'C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test\Client.java';
```

Comment: Hi Joe, you've asked a whole series of questions about this with unsatisfactory results. I would recommend a different tack: ask a question about how to connect to a running JVM in *pure Java*. Java experts will surely be able to help you with that. Once you have that figured out, try to run that code with `Inline::Java`; if it doesn't work, post a question showing the code you tried and the exact error you get. If there's actual code and a specific error message, you are much more likely to get help.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was able to write a simple hello world using RMI to communicate between JVMs in pure java, my problem when i tried to implement the client code in perl using Inline was that once it compiled it could not find the Server class.
I didn't make any changes to the java code, just pointed the perl script to it...

Comment: Then post the code you used and the *exact* text of the error(s) you got. You can edit the code into this question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Any suggestions now?

Comment: With an Applet? You can't connect an external JVM to the JVM running in the browser due to the Java security model. I don't mean it's difficult, I mean you *cannot* do it. The only thing the Applet can connect to is the server it was loaded from.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry, miscommunication on my part, its an OSGi app, not an applet. Edited the question.

Comment: You should also include the Perl script you used. And I'm guessing this is just a typo, but you're missing a closing brace `}` in your Java code. This is now a *much* better question than the ones you asked previously, so I hope somebody can help you. If you don't get an answer in the next two days, somebody can [post a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question to give it more attention, so you don't need to continue opening new questions.

Comment: You need to configure the CLASSPATH for Inline::Java (and it needs to include the package and classes you reference). Does it work when you run it as a standalone Java process to connect to your OSGi container?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, it works when not used through Inline,
What do i point CLASSPATH to? the Hello() interface?

Comment: What CLASSPATH do you use to run it without perl?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test

Comment: @ElliottFrisch
 this is my revised perl

      use Inline (Java => Config => DIRECTORY => 'tmp');
  use Inline Java => 'C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test\Client.java',
   CLASSPATH => 'C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test',
   STUDY => ['Hello'];

  $obj = Server -> new;
  Server -> sayHello;

Comment: @Joe Perhaps try using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Java#classpath): "To set the `CLASSPATH` globally (which is most probably what you want to do anyways), use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable."

Comment: I solved the problem by using the STUDY function of Inline to access the Server class

Comment: @Joe Great! You should write an answer that shows how you solved it, so people who visit this page in the future can see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by defining classpath and using the STUDY config, like so:

```
    use Inline (Java => Config => DIRECTORY => 'tmp');
    use Inline  Java => 'C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test\Client.java',
    CLASSPATH => 'C:\Users\josesong\Documents\RMI_Test',
        STUDY => ['example.hello.Hello', 'example.hello.Server'];

    $obj = Client -> new();
    $obj -> main([]);
```